# Magento Fancybox form - redirect to product page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, fancybox

I have the following issue. In my Magento store I have changed the "Email to friend" functionality in the product page so that when the link is clicked the form appears in a lightbox iframe. The form works fine and the email is sent.

However, the page is reloaded in the popup and the success message is displayed there. I need to pop-up window to close after the Send button is clicked, so that the product page will reload and display the success message.

This is the code I'm using for the Email to friend link in the product page (template/catalog/product/view/addto.phmtl):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
jQuery("a[rel=fancybox1]").fancybox({            
'type'    : 'iframe',
'width'    : 700, // change the required width
'height'   : 700 // change the required height
 });
 });
</script>

<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>" rel="fancybox1"><?php echo $this->__('Recommend to a friend') ?></a>
```

This is the code for the Send button in the form (template/sendfriend/send.phtml):

```
<button type="submit" class="button<?php if (!$this->canSend()):?> disabled<?php endif ?>"<?php if (!$this->canSend()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif ?>><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Send Email') ?></span></span></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var productSendtofriendForm = new VarienForm('product_sendtofriend_form');
    productSendtofriendForm.submit = function() {
        if(this.validator.validate()) {
            this.form.submit();
        }
    }.bind(productSendtofriendForm);
//]]>
</script>
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: has there any JavaScript issue??

Comment: no, there are no javascript conflicts.

Comment: `I need to pop-up window to close after the Send button is clicked` : bind a `click` event to that button that calls the `parent.$.fancybox.close()` API method.